# Opening Fragment from a DialogFragment (replacing the Dialogs parent)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

Let's say I have Fragment A, from which I open a `DialogFragment` like this:

```
FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = (FragmentActivity) view.getContext();
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment prev = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
if (prev != null) {
  ft.remove(prev);
}
ft.addToBackStack(null);
DialogFragment fragmentDialog = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
fragmentDialog.show(ft, "dialog");
```

From this Dialog, after clicking (positive / neutral / negative) button, I want to open Fragment B, which should replace Fragment A.

In the Dialog's onClick method I run a callback method of parent Activity:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
  switch(which) {
    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL:
      detailsCallbacks.openMoreDetails(); 
      break;
  }
}
```

And finally my Activity's `openMoreDetails()` method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void openMoreDetails() {
  Fragment fragmentB = Fragment.newInstance();
  FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentB);
  ft.addToBackStack(null);
  ft.commit();
}
```

What I get is strange. Fragment B blinks on the screen just for a fraction of a second and then is replaced (covered?) by Fragment A again.

When I click the 'up' button I get back from Fragment A, so none of these transactions were added to the back stack. I would like to show Fragment B and then, when pressing the 'up' button, go back to Fragment A.

Is it somehow possible? And what's wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 3):

Just had the same problem:

Fragment A display a custom dialog fragment.

At click on one of the buttons of the dialog fragment, I wanted to remove the dialog and show Fragment B.

Fragment B was displayed and instantly disappear. My screen was displaying Fragment A again.

What was **wrong** on my initial implementation:

```
private void onClickInscription() {
    FragmentInscription frag = FragmentInscription.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.main, frag);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
    dismiss();
}
```

And the **correct** one:

```
private void onClickInscription() {
    dismiss();
    FragmentInscription frag = FragmentInscription.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.main, frag);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

So try to call dismiss first on your dialog then apply the `FragmentTransction`

Comment: Is there a way to open a fragment without closing dialogfragment. because till we do not dismiss dialogfragment , fragment does not show because dialogfragment is overlapping the new fragment

Answer (score 2):

I know this it's been a long time since the problem was posted, but I solved it by adding a `if(fragmentB.getView != null)` before the replace statement.

It finally doesn't do the flash and disappear thing. (:

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be opening the dialog from FragmentA. Implement a callback from your FragmentA to your activity and let the activity handle all fragment transactions.

Comment: It still just blinks over and right after Fragment A appears. When clicking back / up, I get same action as when I clicked back / up from Fragment A, so Fragment B was neither displayed (for more than half a second) nor added to back stack.

Comment: I've rebuild the concept without problems... try using `FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = getActivity();` instead of what you're doing: `FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = (FragmentActivity) view.getContext();`

Comment: But I must add, that I used a different approach then you. Whenever I call another Fragment. I put the code in the Fragment Activity and let it handle the transactions. I think it's cleaner coding, since Fragments shouldn't call or remove each other. It's the Activites job to do so.

Comment: Yeah, your approach is definitely cleaner then mine.. Gonna change this in all over my app. This, however, didn't solve the problem. The strange thing is, that the Fragment B actually appears for a fraction of second and then is replaced by Fragment A again.

Comment: What happens if you remove this line `Fragment prev = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
if (prev != null) {
  ft.remove(prev);
}`